Db2 ESQL or DB2 SQL control statement how to get output
Background:
In DB2 SQL control statements, also called SQL Procedural Language (SQL PL), in v 12.X
they  call them ESQL. Just started trying to program in this with DB2.
What I want to do:
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    FOR X AS Select to return a list of tables
    DO
      Run a couple of selects using the list of tables from the above 1st select
          and have the output returned out side of the BEGIN.. END block
    END FOR;
  END;

Results:
Both of these next select statements work fine outside of BEGIN..END.
Testing on db2 11.5.9 on WIN 2019, testing under the CLPPLUS CLI.
BEGIN ATOMIC
    FOR V_ROW AS SELECT RTRIM(substr(TABNAME,1,30)) as Table_Name FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA='MYUSER1' AND TABNAME LIKE 'DOC%' ORDER BY TABNAME with ur;
    DO
    SELECT count(*) from MYUSER1.V_ROW.Table_Name with ur;
  END FOR;
END;

Output:
Get nothing out.  So, I ASSUME no syntax errors.
However, I get no output either is the second select not printing to the screen??
Questions:
I have been looking and I don't see an obvious way to direct output outside of the
BEGIN ...END block.  What am I missing?
